# how to build a model for 1 dimension data (data after pca/zca process) in keras?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, pca

I'm trying to make a binary classification model for color images,
which contains to classes : a.intact b. damaged

I build a model like below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]
                ))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))



model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.35))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, name = 'output')) #output
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Since I didn't get expected result.
I tried saliency map and it shown that the model didn't 
detect the defects at all.
After different image process like  grayscale or histgram equalization 
and random augmentation method.
It still not working at all. 
Now I want to give a try on PCA/ZCA process to my data.

this is  PCA/ZCA code I found from internet:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=150, whiten=True, random_state=42)
n_samples = len(X_train)
X_train = X_train.reshape((n_samples, -1))
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train)

n_samples = len(X_test)
X_test = X_test.reshape((n_samples, -1))
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)

pca = PCA(whiten=True)
transformed = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
pca.whiten = False
zca = pca.inverse_transform(transformed)
```

Since it transform my data into a 1 dimension array,
I got this ERROR message:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

Any idea to build appropriate model or any way to modify the original one to fit 
my data in ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to reshape your data to fit your model's input layer, or alternatively adjust your model so that it can deal with a 1-dimensional input. Which of the two options makes more sense depends a lot on your data and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for help, can you recommend some resource like turtorial or document for either option ? For future study , I want to understand more about both two method.

Comment: oh I just found out how to reshape the array to fit the model.

Comment: But i still want to know how to build model for different dataset.

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow. You will need to research yourself which type of model will work in your specific use case, there are no general rules. If you have specific questions e.g. on how to implement a model or how to deal with a specific problem, you can ask a new question.